# XPath query to access "related" nodes by look-up on a "relation" element

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a piece of XML similar to the following:

```
<root>
  <person>
     <key>1</key>
  </person>
  <person>
     <key>2</key>
  </person>
  <dog>
     <key>3</key>
  </dog>
  <relations>
    <petOwnership>
      <personRef>1</personRef>
      <dogRef>3</dogRef>
    </petOwnership>
  </relations>
</root>
```

I need an XPath query that, starting on a given person node, will return the correct dog node that is related to it. I first thought of something like:

```
../dog[key=../relations/*[personRef=???]/dogRef]
```

I need to find a way of referencing the current person key where the question marks are. I've tried the root() function but my XPath engine (Java) tells me there's no such function.

Any tips or ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XPath, there is only one "current" node/context. I think it is not possible to do what you intend in one single XPath expression.

In order to relate two nodes other than by structure (axes like ancestor, child, sibling, etc.) you need multiple XPaths and use results of one in the other, i.e. get the `./key/text()` in a variable and use it for `???`.

Comment: The problem is we are using a dynamic XPath evaluator that takes the XPath queries from an external source. However, we have implemented a home-made extension to have nested XPath queries (i.e. execute ./key/text() and replace it's value before running the parent query). Thanks for your answer, anyway :).